# Needs help in below css code

Tags: jquery, css

Please guide me how to make height 0 of `<ul id="nav">` and `<ul class="sub-menu">` from below code and how implement jQuery to `<div class="handle">` for shown down on click/touch.

I'd try with `ul` to set `max-height:0;` but no any changes has been occur. I also try with `ul#nav li` to set `max-height:0;` but no way.

```css
@charset"utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul#nav li {
  background: #fff;
  float: left;
}
ul#nav li a {
  color: black;
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
ul#nav li a:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: white;
}
ul#nav li .sub-list {
  float: none;
}
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}
ul#nav li:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
.handle {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  body {
    background: #CFF;
  }
  ul#nav li {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .handle {
    display: block;
    background: #093;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="nav.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <div class="handle">Menu</div>
      <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Available Stock</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Purchase</a>

          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="sub-list"><a href="#">Purchase Return</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
          <li> <a href="#">Sale</a>

            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li class="sub-list"><a href="#">Sale Return</a>

              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Cash Recieve</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Cash Payment</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Cash Recieve</a>

          </li>
          <li> <a href="#">New</a>

            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li class="sub-list"><a href="#">New Customer</a>

              </li>
              <li class="sub-list"><a href="#">New Supplier</a>

              </li>
              <li class="sub-list"><a href="#">New Town</a>

              </li>
              <li class="sub-list"><a href="#">New Product</a>

              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Opening Stock</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Gate Pass</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sale History</a>

          </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the height of your UL to 0, it's going to work but the content of your UL will still be visible even if it overflows. To hide it you need to set the overflow like this :

```
#nav {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

If you want to show/hide when you click on your 'handle' you need to remove the display:none. You should also change the class handle for an ID (to improve performances with jquery) Then in jquery you need to listen the click event and change the height of the UL accordingly like this for example :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#handle').on('click', function() {
        $('#nav').toggleClass('shown');
  });
});
```

And add a new CSS rule to show your UL when it has the class 'shown'

```
#nav.shown {
 height: auto;
}
```

However, there are some cleaner way to achieve this. I will update this answer with a fiddle if I have a moment. I hope it helped anyway.

Edit : This is still not the way I would have used, but I edit to answer to your comment. Do not forget to load jQuery !

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#handle').on('click', function() {
        $('#nav').toggleClass('shown');
  });
});
```

```css
@charset"utf-8";

/* CSS Document */
 body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
#handle {
    display: none;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul#nav li {
    background: #fff;
    float: left;
}
ul#nav li a {
    color: black;
    display: block;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
ul#nav li a:hover {
    background: #000;
    color: white;
}
ul#nav li .sub-list {
    float: none;
}
.sub-menu {
    display: none;
}
ul#nav li:hover .sub-menu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background: #CFF;
    }
    #nav {
      height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    ul#nav li {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #nav.shown {
        height: auto;
    }
    #handle {
        display: block;
        background: #093;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <nav>
        <div id="handle">Menu</div>
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Available Stock</a>

            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">Purchase</a>

                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="sub-list"><a href="#">Purchase Return</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
                <li> <a href="#">Sale</a>

                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li class="sub-list"><a href="#">Sale Return</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Cash Recieve</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Cash Payment</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Cash Recieve</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="#">New</a>

                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li class="sub-list"><a href="#">New Customer</a>

                        </li>
                        <li class="sub-list"><a href="#">New Supplier</a>

                        </li>
                        <li class="sub-list"><a href="#">New Town</a>

                        </li>
                        <li class="sub-list"><a href="#">New Product</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Opening Stock</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Gate Pass</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Sale History</a>

                </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: I've done according to your instructions but on click not working please edit my code.

Comment: I haven't seen the media query, i just realized what you try to do. Here is a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3b0t6dog/

Comment: i want to make it multilevel from purchase to purchase return, sale to sale return etc. Please give me idea to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide/show an element with jQuery there's no need to manipulate its height.

First, make the `.handle` visible, removing `display: none;`.

Then hide your menu and attach to the desired events to toggle its visibility:

```
$('#nav').hide();

$('.handle').on('click', function(){
    $('#nav').toggle();
})
```

Comment: Still you don't provide any details what in particular is not working for you. Here, have at it http://jsfiddle.net/dekkard/auLqx5d2/

Comment: Toggle is deprecated. It's better to use toggleClass and manipulate via CSS.